# Maven using local spark library

Tags: amazon-web-services, maven, apache-spark

Due to a recent EKS update on AWS I was not anymore able to run spark jobs on AWS (kubernetes client version had to be upgraded).
Therefore, I have been building the last Spark snapshot version (2.4.5-SNAPSHOT, it contains the bugfix I need) successfully.
Now I want to add it to my project, replacing the old 2.3.3 version.

Unfortunately I get some compilation error (see below).

I am probably doing something wrong with my pom.xml file. The final goal is to fetch jar files from remote and from local (the repo)

Ideas?
Thanks!

P.s.
Ubuntu 18.04 + intellij

```
        The relevant part of the pom.xml file are the following:


        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>


    I add my local repo...

         <!-- My local repo where the jar file has been placed -->
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>Local</id>
                    <name>Repository Spark</name>
                    <url>/home/cristian/repository/sparkyspark/spark</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>

        <groupId>sparkjob</groupId>
        <artifactId>sparkjob</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
        </properties>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>entry.Main</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>

                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>make-assembly</id>
                            <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>single</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <rules><dependencyConvergence/></rules>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>



        ...

        <dependencies>
        .... 
        ....
    here it is, the jar file I need
         <!-- The last Spark jar file -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
                <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
        ...
        ....
         </dependencies>

This is the error message, the path is correct...the file is there.
Ideas? :)
```

ERROR:

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project sparkjob:sparkjob:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:jar:2.4.5-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:jar:2.4.5-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:pom:2.4.5-SNAPSHOT from/to Local (/home/cristian/repository/sparkyspark/spark): Cannot access /home/cristian/repository/sparkyspark/spark with type default using the available connector factories.....
```

UPDATE: hard wiring the path seems to be a good work-around...

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>/home/cristian/repository/sparkyspark/spark/spark-core_2.11-2.4.5-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Did you perform `mvn deploy` to deploy your jar to Local Repository? In addition to that, you can define snapshot repository which will point to the folder you have mentioned above. Note that the folder you have mentioned will follow the repository structure. PS: I personally didn't like the approach of specifying systemPath inside pom.xml. If possible move these settings to maven configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a folder as a repository you have to use `file://` protocol.

So you repository config should be.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
       <id>Local</id>
       <name>Repository Spark</name>
       <url>file:///home/cristian/repository/sparkyspark/spark</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I keep getting the same error using file:/// or just file:// . Could not resolve dependencies for project sparkjob:sparkjob:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11:jar:2.4.5-SNAPSHOT in file:///home/cristian/repository/sparkyspark/spark

Comment: what is the content of /home/cristian/repository/sparkyspark/spark folder

Comment: I add the target output of the spark maven compilation: analysis                        original-spark-core_2.11-2.4.5-SNAPSHOT.jar
antrun                          scala-2.11
extra-resources                 spark-core_2.11-2.4.5-SNAPSHOT.jar
jars                            spark-core_2.11-2.4.5-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar
kubernetes-model-4.4.2.jar      spark-core_2.11-2.4.5-SNAPSHOT-tests.jar
maven-archiver                  spark-core_2.11-2.4.5-SNAPSHOT-test-sources.jar
maven-shared-archive-resources  tmp
org